# How can I remove all data of a picker?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I have a picker and I want change its data, then I clear all data and put the new data, but I don't know how line is used to do that. I've already tried:

```
cidadepicker.Items.RemoveAt(i); //with a for
```

and

```
cidadepicker.Items.Clear();
```

as well.

I am using Xamarin Forms. I don't know what I should do.

Answer (score 2):

Use Observable collection of `<string>` (or your model) and bind it to your picker. From there you can manipulate your picker's children via you Binding collection.

Inside your ViewModel;

```
   private ObservableCollection<string> _pickerItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public YourViewModel()
        {
            PickerItems.Add("item1");
            PickerItems.Add("item2");
            PickerItems.Add("item3");
        }


        public ObservableCollection<string> PickerItems
        {
            get { return _pickerItems; }
            set
            {
                _pickerItems = value;
                OnPopertyChanged("PickerItems");
            }
        }
```

Then in your activity;

```
private YourViewModel ViewModel=new YourViewModel();

BindingContext=ViewModel;
```

Inside your picker in xaml;

```
ItemSource={Binding PickerItems}
```

And now you can manipulate you item source from activity by calling;

```
ViewModel.PickerItems.Clear() //to clear items
ViewMOdel.PickerItems.Add("New Item") // add item
```

PS: As long as you have OnPropertyChanged in your Getter/Setter ( PickerItems) the UI will update automatically. Hope I helped

Comment: If I have a list with 20 items and I changed it, 10 items, for example, this does my picker have only 10 tems?
it is what I want

Comment: Now it mixs the old items with the news in the layout

Comment: what is the OnPopertyChanged("PickerItems")?

Comment: private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

Comment: Add the name of person you are writing to like @YuriS or we don't get notified on new comment

Comment: Without OnPropertyChanged your Listview UI wont update. Thats why u need it.

Answer (score 0):

Set `SelectedIndex = -1.` This resets the picker such that no items are selected.

```
YourPicker.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

I want it shows the data and after the data dissapear

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

When ItemsSource of a picker is binded with a dataSource, the Items is already a read-only collection.

for instance:

```
var Lst_Items = new List<string>();
Lst_items.add("item 1");
Lst_items.add("item 2");
Lst_items.add("item 3");

cidadepicker.ItemsSource = Lst_Items;

//to remove all data from your picker simply.

Lst_Items.clear();

cidadepicker.ItemsSource = Lst_Items;

//or you can simply set the item source to be null.

cidadepicker.ItemsSource = null;
```

Comment: thank u 
but it continues show the list after I do that